Dusk browser testing scripts stopped working in Laravel v10
I'm using Laravel v10.45.1 and my Dusk browser testing scripts stopped working on my Apple M3 Pro running Sonoma 14.5. I think an upgrade to my Google Chrome browser app may have broken it.
When I run:
php artisan dusk
The error I see is:
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: 
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 126
Current browser version is 129.0.6668.71 with binary path 
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

I tried installing the support driver version...
php artisan dusk:chrome-driver 126
I get the following feedback..
ChromeDriver binary successfully installed for version 126.0.6478.182.
But I rerun php artisan dusk, and get the same error.
I updated Dusk to the latest v7.13.0.
I tried clearing configs and clearing cache.
How can I fix this issue?

Current browser version is 129 so you need to install driver version 129 too

I install chrome-driver 129, get this feedback ChromeDriver binary successfully installed for version 129.0.6668.70.
But I still get the error above:
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 126 Current browser version is 129.0.6668.71 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

check if the chrome driver on your pc is updated

The Github repo told me to upgrade to the latest version of Dusk, v8, to resolve this issue. I haven't done that yet, but will report back here if that ends up being the fix.

Upgrading to Dusk v8 (which also required I upgrade the version of PHP that my project was using to v8.2 & upgrade the version of phpunit to v10) successfully fixed this issue.
